# how to assign a char to array?

Tags: c

```
int compress(char str[]) {

  char tempStr [256];
  int i,j, counter=0;


     if (!isdigit(str[i]) && (!isspace(str[i]))) {
        tempStr[j] = str[i];  
        j++;
        printf("%c", tempStr[i]); 
     } else {
        counter++;
     }

     str = tempStr;
}

char str[] = "abc abc abc 123";
result = compress(&str);
```

Question:

1. how to assign a `str` `char` to `tempStr`?
2. how to replace `str` to `tempStr` in function `compress`? I think `str = tempStr` is wrong

thanks

Comment: Just exactly where is the variable `i` defined?  I think you are missing part of your example in your example.

Comment: @Edwin:  I see `i` is defined. (and I don't see any edit-history on the question).

Comment: Funny, I could have sworn it wasn't there before.  Perhaps I'm just up too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Your code miss tempStr defination, like **char tempStr[LENGTH]**, make sure **LENGTH** is big enough.
2.C string should be terminated by '\0', so you need set tempStr[j] = '\0' after the loop (which is missing I think). Then you can use strcpy copy tempStr to str.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are a bit confused about strings, arrays and pointers.

`char str[] = "abc abc abc 123";` means that somewhere in memory you have an array with those characters. when so declared, the 'str' is constant and cannot be set to point somewhere else.

instead you need assign each individual character which is sort of what you started to do
in your function with the statement `tempStr[j] = str[i]:`

you need to loop through the characters in str and check each character, then assign the char to the tempStr which should be at least as large as the original str[] array.

something like

```
char *tempStr = calloc( strlen( str ) + 1, 1 ); // allocates a buffer +1 char for \0
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen( str ); ++i)
{
  if (!isdigit(str[i]) && (!isspace(str[i]))) 
  {
    tempStr[j++] = str[i];  
    printf("%c", str[i]); 
  } 
}
```

now you have removed some characters from str[] however you need now to move
back the contents of tempStr to str, this can be done with a strcpy:

```
strcpy( str, tempStr );
```

then free the buffer

```
free( tempStr );
```

and Bob is your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `memcpy` or `strcpy` (if it's a null terminated string).

In the example, `tempStr` is not defined, so I'm guessing it's an array of `char`s. Although, you'll probably need a loop somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

```
 char tempStr [256];
```

`tempStr` is a character array that can hold 256 characters.

**But what happens with this statement- `str = tempStr;` ?**

When you say, `tempStr`, what you get is the pointer to the first element of the array (i.e., &tempStr[0] ). So, with the statement you aren't actually copying the elements of `tempStr` to `str`. The rvalue is of type `char*` but the lvalue is of type `char []`, which are incompatible and results compilation error.

To actually copy the elements of the array, you should use `strcpy`.